# Verify if dataframe contains content in dict of lists

Tags: python, pandas

I realize the title is a bit fuzzy but let me illustrate.

I have a dataframe that (simplified) looks like this:

```
Date | transaction | amount

01-01-2020 | something keywordA something | 50

01-01-2020 | something something keywordB | 152

02-01-2020 | keywordA something else | 200
```

etc

Then the first thing I do is add an empty column called 'category' like this:

```
df['Category'] = ''
```

Now I then also have a dict of lists like this:

```
categories={'category A':['keywordA','keywordB'], 'category B':['keywordC']}
```

etc

Now what I want to do is see if the transaction column for each row contains one of the keywords and if it contains eg. keywordA I want the category column to be filled in with 'category A'.

So first of all I am not sure if using a dict of lists is the way to go here. Secondly I could probably go row by row, do a contains type function and compare to every item in the dict but from what I have read iterating over each row is normally bad practice when you are using pandas and just intuitively this will scale very badly.

So.. any hints as to what direction I should be looking at ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what i understand , you can do this with `series.str.extract` and `series.map` after reversing the dictionary:

```
d = {a:k for k,v in categories.items() for a in v}
#{'keywordA': 'category A', 'keywordB': 'category A', 'keywordC': 'category B'}
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(d.keys()))
df['Category'] = df['transaction'].str.extract('('+pat+')',expand=False).map(d)
```

---

```
print(df)

        Date                   transaction  amount    Category
0 2020-01-01  something keywordA something      50  category A
1 2020-01-01  something something keywordB     152  category A
2 2020-02-01       keywordA something else     200  category A
```

Comment: Hi, I will try that.

But as I am just getting back to python after a 4-5 year break, mind explaining what that 2nd line does exactly?

I get the first line, you basically make a new dict where the keys are the list items and value equal to the original key. Third line extracts a pattern from transaction string and maps it to the new dict. But the pattern defining is a bit abstract.

Comment: @Thustra the second line defines a pattern which joins the keys of the newly formed dictionary by a pipe and formats with a `'\b'` which is a [word boundary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) so as to check exact word match before mapping a category..!!

Comment: that works like a charm :) Thanks a lot, I still need to work a bit on understanding how, but easier to read the docs with something you know that works right there.